# c# парсинг логов

Tags: c#, парсер

необходимо отследить доставку сообщения по логам. 
Как можно это сделать с помощью Regex?
[Full Log.txt](http://rgho.st/6KkWlgRJ7)

```
Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:57.886: <-- MAIL FROM: <Marion@frd.ru>
Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:57.887: --> 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:57.890: <-- RCPT TO: <almira@frd.ru>
Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:57.895: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:57.898: <-- RCPT TO: <Lyahova@frd.ru>
Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:57.903: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK

Mon 2019-02-25 01:31:58.063: --> 250 2.6.0 Ok, message saved <Message-ID: <016401d4cccb$3a0b8d50$ae22a7f0$@frd.ru>>
Mon 2019-02-25 01:43:00.581: <-- QUIT
Mon 2019-02-25 01:43:00.581: --> 221 2.0.0 See ya in cyberspace
Mon 2019-02-25 01:43:00.581: SMTP session successful (Bytes in/out: 21527/449)
```

Нужно получить Marion@frd.ru, almira@frd.ru, Lyahova@frd.ru, SMTP session successful

Comment: Ваша ссылка на лог дает: `Доступ к информационному ресурсу ограничен на основании ФЗ от 27.07.2006 г. №149-ФЗ "Об информации, информационных технологиях и о защите информации"`

Comment: Задача не совсем ясна. Нужно просто получить список email, но только тех, после которых есть SMTP session successful? Что считать началом отправки сообщения? То что там написано MAIL FROM: Какая-то почта?

То есть формат такой: MAIL FROM это начало отправки сообщений. Далее обязательно должно идти Sender OK и какие-то получатели, выводим список только тех получателей, у которых написано Recipient OK. Верно?

Comment: Совершенно верно, получилось это сделать с помощью циклов. Это работает, но только для файла меньше 5 мб, иначе цикл намертво зависает(Если указываю какую почту ищу, то все хорошо).

Comment: Проблема явно не в циклах. Так можно сказать почти про любую программу, что она сделана с помощью циклов. Нужно читать не весь файл в память, а читать его построчно. Какой цикл и где зависает? И что значит цикл зависает? В дебаге пробовали отлаживать цикл в тот момент, когда он "завис"? То есть, ставили точку останова и программа не останавливалась на ней? Я бы написал решение этой задачи при помощи конечного автомата, вроде такого: [конечный автомат](https://i.imgur.com/GCUXoJx.jpg), где авал - это состояние, а стрелка это событие перехода в другое состояние. Конец блока - это QUIT в логах.

Comment: @CasperSC Проблему решил, файл изначально построчно считывал. Проблема была в циклах, было 3 вложенных(600 000 * 3 выходило минут 20~) то есть без зависания.  Файл распарсил, убрал все лишние и кинул в 3 потока. При любом условие работает меньше секунды. С автоматами не сталкивался, почитаю

Comment: @Андрей, этот форум предназначен не для того, чтобы помочь конкретно вам и всё, а чтобы любой в будущем мог найти решение. Вы вполне могли бы выложить своё решение в качестве ответа. Я мог бы попробовать, к примеру, выложить своё на тех же конечных автоматах. Вообще, если все логи имеют строго такой формат, то будет норм работать. Заодно бы проверили ваш вариант на ошибки. Да и мой. Но я не настаиваю, дело ваше.

Comment: @CasperSC, Формат логи могут иметь иной, в зависимости от ошибок.

Comment: Вся суть в том что бы понять когда происходит ошибка. В данные момент мне удалось получить доставлено письмо или нет~, какая ошибка~, кому и от кого отправлено. Сам код скину позже, но мне не нравиться сам подход/реализация... Ваш пример не удалось запустить, так как студия попросила докачать компоненты, но увы места не жестком нету. Попробую завтра решить проблему

Comment: @Андрей, могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на большие логи? Я автозаменой заменю там все фамилии, домены, как впрочем, я и сделал в ответе. Мне интересно парсер допилить :). Ещё бы требования более подробные. Какую инфу нужно получить. Можно даже временную ссылку, мне бы на чём-то тестить

Comment: @Андрей, да, там проект под .NET Core просто сделан. Можно создать проект другого типа, например, для .NET Framework и всё туда скопировать. Должно работать. Но с таким подходом вам будет сложно получать изменения из репозитория, так что лучше как-то решить проблему с местом и докачать, что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Набросал парсер логов с самописными классами машины состояний.

**Disclaimer**

> Я особо нигде не подсматривал, написал как придумал, в принципе, это
>   был первый раз, когда я вообще попробовал использовать машину
>   состояний в виде отдельной её реализации и классов для каждого состояния. Не пропадать же потраченному времени зря, так что выкладываю.

Я понимаю, что в консоль писать в реализации классов состояний - это не самая лучшая идея, но пора остановиться, слишком много времени потратил на эту софтину :)

Ещё, какие плюсы я вижу в использовании машины состояний - это то, что в каждом состоянии только часть своих проверок, а не проверки на каждой итерации сразу всего что можно, так же отсутствие ветвлений в виде if else или использования switch case.

В репозитории код может меняться, улучшаться и т.д.

[Ссылка на репозиторий](https://bitbucket.org/CasperSC/fsmlogparser)

[Ссылка на пример логов, на которых я проверял](https://bitbucket.org/CasperSC/fsmlogparser/src/master/log.txt)

[Ссылка на схему машины состояний](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLCU5.jpg)

[image: Схема машины состояний]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FsmLogParser.Core;
using FsmLogParser.Logs;
using FsmLogParser.Model;
using FsmLogParser.States;
using FsmLogParser.States.Enums;

namespace FsmLogParser
{
    public class Program
    {
        #region Entry point

        private static Program _program;

        private static Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            _program = new Program();
            return _program.Run(args);
        }

        #endregion

        private const int NOT_ENOUGH_POSITIONAL_CMD_ARGS_SPECIFIED_ERROR = 1;
        private const int FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR = 2;
        private const int EXIT_SUCCESS = 0;

        private LogReader _logReader;
        private Dictionary<int, SessionInfo> _infos;

        public int IterationCounter { get; set; }

        private async Task<int> Run(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not enough positional command-line arguments specified!");
                return NOT_ENOUGH_POSITIONAL_CMD_ARGS_SPECIFIED_ERROR;
            }

            string pathToFile = args[0];
            if (!File.Exists(pathToFile))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File \"{pathToFile}\" not found.");
                return FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR;
            }

            try
            {
                var fsm = BuildStateMachine();

                _infos = new Dictionary<int, SessionInfo>();
                using (_logReader = new LogReader(pathToFile))
                {
                    _logReader.OpenFile();
                    await fsm.Start(this);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Results:");
                foreach (var (iteration, sessionInfo) in _infos)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{iteration.ToString()}: {sessionInfo}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        private static StateMachine<ParserState, ParserEvent, Program> BuildStateMachine()
        {
            var builder = new StateMachineBuilder<ParserState, ParserEvent, Program>();

            // Схема машины состояний: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLCU5.jpg
            builder.SetInitialState<StartSessionSearchState>(ParserState.StartSessionSearch)
                // Перейти в состояние SenderSearchState, если сейчас состояние
                // ParserState.StartSessionSearch и пришло событие ParserEvent.StartSessionFound
                .AddTransition<SenderSearchState>(ParserState.StartSessionSearch, ParserEvent.StartSessionFound)
                .AddTransition<RecipientSearchState>(ParserState.SenderSearch, ParserEvent.SenderFound)
                .AddTransition<RecipientSearchState>(ParserState.RecipientSearch, ParserEvent.RecipientFound)
                .AddTransition<SessionTokenSearchState>(ParserState.RecipientSearch, ParserEvent.EndOfBlockFound)
                .AddTransition<StartSessionSearchState>(ParserState.SessionTokenSearch, ParserEvent.SuccessfulSessionTokenFound)
                .AddTransition<StartSessionSearchState>(ParserState.SessionTokenSearch, ParserEvent.EndOfSessionFound)
                .AddTransition<DoneState>(ParserState.StartSessionSearch, ParserEvent.EndOfSearchRangeReached)
                .AddTransition<DoneState>(ParserState.SenderSearch, ParserEvent.EndOfSearchRangeReached)
                .AddTransition<DoneState>(ParserState.RecipientSearch, ParserEvent.EndOfSearchRangeReached)
                .AddTransition<DoneState>(ParserState.SessionTokenSearch, ParserEvent.EndOfSearchRangeReached);

            return builder.Build();
        }

        public Task<string> GetNextLine()
        {
            return _logReader.ReadLine();
        }

        public SessionInfo GetSessionInfo(int iteration)
        {
            if (!_infos.ContainsKey(iteration))
            {
                _infos.Add(iteration, new SessionInfo());
            }

            return _infos[iteration];
        }
    }
}
```

Пример одного из состояний и переходы:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FsmLogParser.Core.Interfaces;
using FsmLogParser.States.Enums;

namespace FsmLogParser.States
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="ParserState.RecipientSearch"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class RecipientSearchState : IState<Program, ParserEvent, ParserState>
    {
        private readonly Regex _regex;

        public ParserState State { get; } = ParserState.RecipientSearch;

        public RecipientSearchState()
        {
            var options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
            _regex = new Regex(@"RCPT TO:\s+<{0,1}([a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)>{0,1}", options);
        }

        public async Task DoWork(IStateMachine<ParserState, Program, ParserEvent> fsm, Program context)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string line = await context.GetNextLine();

                if (line == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Current state: {fsm.CurrentState}. SendEvent({nameof(ParserEvent.EndOfSearchRangeReached)})");
                    fsm.SendEvent(ParserEvent.EndOfSearchRangeReached);
                    break;
                }

                Match match = await Task.Run(() => _regex.Match(line));
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Current state: {fsm.CurrentState}. SendEvent({nameof(ParserEvent.RecipientFound)})");
                    if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
                    {
                        var info = context.GetSessionInfo(context.IterationCounter);
                        info.Recipients.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
                    }
                    fsm.SendEvent(ParserEvent.RecipientFound);
                    break;
                }

                if (await Task.Run(() => Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s+QUIT$", RegexOptions.Compiled)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Current state: {fsm.CurrentState}. SendEvent({nameof(ParserEvent.EndOfBlockFound)})");
                    fsm.SendEvent(ParserEvent.EndOfBlockFound);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чтение логов из файла

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FsmLogParser.Logs
{
    public class LogReader : IDisposable
    {
        private FileStream _fileStream;
        private BufferedStream _bufferedStream;
        private StreamReader _reader;

        public string PathToFile { get; }

        public LogReader(string pathToFile)
        {
            PathToFile = pathToFile;
        }

        public void OpenFile()
        {
            _fileStream = File.Open(PathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            _bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(_fileStream);
            _reader = new StreamReader(_bufferedStream);
        }

        public Task<string> ReadLine()
        {
            return _reader.ReadLineAsync();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _reader?.Dispose();
            _bufferedStream?.Dispose();
            _fileStream?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Остальное по ссылке, слишком много кода нужно сюда скопировать.